# How should Data be handled when developing automated testing frameworks?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#, test-data, data-analysis

Currently i am using C#/Selenium to develop the automated testing framework. To run the tests i developed test fixtures which still use C#/Selenium but are ran with NUnit and are separated from the framework.

To prevent validation failure, data duplication, and other pain points we have a test script that is ran during the setup that wipes the local instance database to a clean slate each time a new test is run.

We currently use class level form objects to represent data which are passed into the frame work method calls. The issue that arises is duplicate data or duplicate path traversal through the system can happen. To combat this we encapsulate code but this can become unmanageable as even the slightest change in the path traversal of the test(Change in steps) will be different than the encapsulated method.

To finalize the question, what methods are used for data control when developing automated test frameworks with Selenium